# Illogical counter restart for starting bounty

Tags: feature-request, bounties

As you well know, you have to wait for 48 hours to start a bounty for a question.

Whenever you edit a question, the 48-hour timer starts counting again.

Though I understand the principle behind the behavior (waiting to see if your modifications had an effect), it makes no sense to me given that 48 hours is more than enough time for a question to be out there!

What do you think about this?

Comment: I read "Illogic computer restart for bounties", thinking that you were gonna say your computer restarted every time you opened a bounty o.o

Comment: @Kop LOL that would have startled everyone in stackoverflow and superuser, I think pople might have gone crazy over that! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that must be a new thing.

Possibly [to avoid the issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64459/rolling-back-a-completely-changed-question) where Users that don't want to wait the 48 hours before offering a bounty could simply edit an unrelated old question and offer the bounty straight away.

But I presume you can offer the bounty then edit the question immediately afterwards?