# Questions changed on getting answer to current question

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I have seen that users ask questions related to code and, when they get solution to their current problem, they just make those changes to code in current question itself and change the question asking their next problem. This makes the already given answers irrelevant to the current question.

So is there any way to mark such questions?   I just commented that its better to add a new question than editing same question.

Comment: @Servy: That's not quite the same thing.

Comment: this is an interesting question. But i'm not sure people want to edit versus ask a new fresh Q . Snce visibility drops a lot . Hmm , Ok I can see why they might, to stretch the 7-question cap

Comment: It seems like a good match to me, @RobertHarvey, but maybe you'd prefer [Rolling back a completely changed question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64459)

Comment: I rolled back that question to a revision that makes sense for the current answers and left a comment for the OP

Comment: @JoshCaswell: I would.

Comment: Maybe a comment cleanup is also adviceable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22308433/creating-a-stack-using-arrays#comment33898906_22308433

Comment: @rene thanks. got it a person with privileges can roll back the question and leave a comment to OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone with editing privileges should roll the post back to its previous revision.  Question askers should not be changing the code in their question unless they made an error posting the actual code they were having a problem with.

If they insist on editing to ask a new question, vote to close the question as "problem can no longer be reproduced."